package accents seems to be incompatible with Unicode-math
I have created the following MWE
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO}

\begin{document}

$\{\underaccent{\bar}{e}_1,\ldots,\underaccent{\bar}{e}_n\}$

\end{document}

The accents package returns a lot of missing } and { errors. If I comment out the unicode-math calls then the MWE compiles without any errors to produce the following:

I have tried loading accents after unicode-math but it does not make any difference. Are these two packages incompatible?

I think it's enough to add {}
as in

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\makeatletter
\def\cc@uaccentset#1{%
  \cc@under{%
    \hbox{%
      $\m@th
       \cc@style
       \mathgroup\cc@group
       \cc@shift
       \scriptscriptstyle#1{}$}}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO}

\begin{document}

$\{\underaccent{\bar}{e}_1,\ldots,\underaccent{\bar}{e}_n\}$

\end{document}


You could report this at https://github.com/jbezos/accents

Thanks for your solution. For a novice like myself, what is the reason you need to add this definition?

@TedBlack the error that you get is a missing argument error as the accent command gets called with no argument, essentially under the e is \hbox{$\bar$]  and this gives an error in the \Umathaccent version. The {} gives an empty base so \hbox{$\bar{}$]

@TedBlack the underbar is rather thin due to the  \scriptscriptstyle but that's part of the original definition I'm not sure why it picks such a small size unconditionally

You might use \mathunderbar, but it's flawed and I provide a fix.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ubar}{m}{%
  \mathunderbar{\kern0pt#1}%
}


\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Bad}

$\mathunderbar{e}$ $\{\mathunderbar{e}_1,\ldots,\mathunderbar{e}_n\}$
$\mathunderbar{y}$ $\{\mathunderbar{y}_1,\ldots,\mathunderbar{y}_n\}$

\subsubsection*{Good}

$\ubar{e}$ $\{\ubar{e}_1,\ldots,\ubar{e}_n\}$
$\ubar{y}$ $\{\ubar{y}_1,\ldots,\ubar{y}_n\}$

\end{document}


